# Convert long strings to html elements in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a string that contain some html in string form, like this one :

```
var string = '<html> ... some code here... </html>';
```

the problem is when i try to convert this string to html element in JQuery if the length of this string be bigger than 28457 characters JQuery convert this string to an array, as you see here :

```
var temp = $(string.substr(0, 28458));
```

if i print "temp" this message is shown :

- jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[102]

[image]

for access to temp i should do my actions like an array

```
temp[12] /* return some html or text element that contain attribute, baseURI, etc. */
```

1. why this message is shown?
2. what can i do for convert string to html if it's length is bigger than 28458 charachters?

thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do actually?

Comment: Its not clear what the problem is.  var temp=$(string.substr(0, 28458)) should be trying to give you a jquery element based on what your string.substr(...) evaluates to

Comment: jQuery is turning your string into a jQuery object (which "pretends" to be an array).  It's doing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: jQuery instances are array-like objects. Is there something wrong with your jQuery instance?

Comment: i wanna work on that array like DOM, but in this state it's not in standard mode for DOM. what can i do?

Comment: @kuroshparsi: What do you mean "standard mode for DOM"?  Maybe your `.substr` is making the string into invalid HTML?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added an example of something that you want to do so it would be easier to understand what the problem is.

Comment: no i try this with only $(string) yet, but the problem not solved.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas no, i don't do nothing with my jquery source.

Comment: I tried your example, and it simply works: http://jsfiddle.net/5Evxa/

Comment: @Juhana this code is part of the big program, all the parts are well just this is my problem.

Comment: Yeah, it's just that nobody can understand your problem. Please make a small example that demonstrates the problem, you don't have to show the entire project.

Comment: @Armin you tried that with just "... some code here... " size, replace ...some code here.. with 28458 characters. then you can see JQuery convert that String to an array.

Comment: @Juhana which part you need, replace that <html> ... some code here... </html> code with long characters, bigger than  28458 and then convert that with $() in jquery. all the problem is this. jquery convert my string to an array.

Comment: @Kurosh Nope: http://jsfiddle.net/5Evxa/1/

Comment: @kuroshparsi: `jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[102]` means that this is a jQuery object with 102 elements.  That's correct.  That's what jQuery is supposed to do with an HTML string.  This is something Chrome does, I think.  It prints `[102]` instead of display 102 elements in the console.

Comment: thanks @Armin, i think my problem is for some Double quotes and Single quotes in my string but i can't remove them, i think i should convert them to single quotes. thanks all.

Comment: You could escape them `'` becomes `\'` what will fit your requirements too

Comment: If quotes were the issue, how are you not getting a syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i find a way, in String to HTML convert via jquery with `$()` if your string length be bigger than 28457 characters JQuery change your string format to Array, so if you wanna use that html elements attribute for search and DOM actions it's not easy to control, the way is at first Convert String to html element, like this

```
$(String)
```

but in this state you can't access to `.html()` so, put this Object to hidden place in your page like div or etc, here i used div with temp id.

```
$('#temp').html($(String));
```

now you can access to `.html()` or other things like complate object.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery have no problem with long Strings to convert to html element the problem is in quotes
 in that string, you should escape them.

Comment: If quotes were the issue, how did you not get any syntax errors?  `var string = '<html><div id='test'></div></html>';` would be a syntax error.

Comment: because i load that content with AJAX before this.

Comment: Are you sure this is your issue?  I've loaded HTML with mixed quotes via AJAX with no issues.  http://jsfiddle.net/jt5u2/

Comment: Oops! you right @Rocket i tested that, i replace ' with " but problem is not solved.
var temp = $(string.replace('\'', '"'));
you can see my code in Armin's link in here : http://jsfiddle.net/5Evxa/2/ 
i mixed :D.

Comment: That example doesn't work because you can't have (un-escaped) newlines in a literal JavaScript string.  Every line needs to end with `\ `, which escapes the newline.

Comment: @Rocket yeah, i just put the content for you to see what is inside that string, but really this content is load in string with AJAX. so we don't need break lines yet.

Comment: Oh ok.  I tested an AJAX request with your example, and it works fine.

Comment: for me this problem shwon jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[171], and 171 is length of arrays, i mixed.

Comment: `jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[171]` is a jQuery object of 171 elements.  You're just seeing that because Chrome doesn't feel like displaying ALL 171 elements in your console.  It's *not* an error.

Comment: Oops! i tried to access to that object with Array! like temp[0] :D it's crazy give me rate down. :(

Comment: should i delete this post? i think it's not useful for others, i'm beginner here.

Comment: :(( @Rocket when i try $(string).html(); my result is null! so if jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[171] is not error and don't convert my content to Array why this happend?

Comment: That's because when you use `.html()` on a jQuery collection, you're only getting the `.html()` of the 1st element.  `$(string).eq(100).html()` (for example) works fine.

Comment: @Rocket you mean i should call all elements of $(string) with a loop? i use "FOR" like this `for (var i=0; i <= temp.length; i++){
console.log(temp[i]);
}`
but i see here some other element with "Text" name that i don't need them.

Comment: What is your end goal?  Why do you need to convert `string` to a jQuery object?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: i wanna call this string in a page and do something with this elements like DOM Actions.

Comment: Then do those "DOM Actions".  Does that not work?  `.html()` might not work on all the elements, but other methods may.

Comment: @Rocket yes `.text()` work but i need parse `.html()` before put that string in place, anyway thanks for your attention i should try other ways.